# "Take your ball and go home" - meaning of this phrase?

Tags: meaning, idioms

On a business website regarding the takeover of a radio station, I noticed this unusual phrase:

> Can't really see Orion Media changing Gold much, unless Global take their ball home and say that if you don't want Heart you can't have Gold and take away the licensing deal.

What exactly does "take your ball and go home" mean? Is it a sporting metaphor?

Is it a good phrase to use in writing (that is, informal writing), or not?

Comment: Be careful using this as it's accusing the ball taker of being unreasonable, unsporting and childish.

Answer (score 15):

This refers to the childhood practice of playing a ball game with your friends, where the ball belongs to one of you. If the game doesn't go your way, you might get upset and leave, taking your ball with you, ending the game for everyone.

Essentially the quote is saying if Global withdraw from the deal, Orion Media will lose both Heart and Gold.

It's perfectly acceptable to use in informal writing.

Comment: The UK equivalent is "take his bat home".

Comment: @Elendil: That is not germane to @Colin Fine's comment. Even if your (very subjective) statements were true, neither addresses his assertion. If "take his bat home" is the phrase he grew up hearing in the UK, I for one would be prepared to take his word for it.

Comment: Noted and deleted.

Comment: Haha - I was going to say that I'd never heard 'take his bat home' then ask if you were a Yorkshireman. I just checked your profile and you are. Sounds perfect in a Yorkshire accent.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Presumably referring to cricket.

Comment: @ColinFine "Take your ball home" is perfectly familiar to this Englishman. To be honest "take your bat home" doesn't quite carry the implication that the game is abandoned that "take your ball home" does because all ball games I know of only have one ball in play at any one time but several of them are played by people who have their own bats.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a schoolkid many years ago, some kids were just bad losers. We would play football in the park, and if their team was losing, they would take their ball and go home. It's the football equivalent of picking up the Monopoly board and throwing it across the room.

Comment: Not exactly, it's not as bad. (1) you can "take the ball home" only if it's yours (usually), while you can mess up the board regardless of who's the owner; (2) if you "take the ball home", people still can resume the game with another ball, maybe at a later time; instead if you throw the board like that the game is no more resumable and you get punched repeatedly in the face.

Comment: I think the big difference here is that "Taking your ball and going home" is not amoral.  Also it is more commonly used as a threat.  As in "we play the game i want or i am taking my ball and going home"  I think the 'technical' term for the other one is "flipping the table"

Answer (score 0):

I was mildly surprised to discover instances of the expression used, in a literal sense, as early as 1894. From "[In Behalf of the New Ulm Ball-Club](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn89081128/1894-08-15/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22ball%2Band%2Bgo%2Bhome%22)," in the *New Ulm [Minnesota] Review* (August 15, 1894):

> The Gibbon [Minnesota] boys say that they came here to play a friendly game. I wish to say that the game was friendly until the Gibbon men started the trouble themselves, which was caused by one of their men calling our catcher by such names as were never before used on our grounds by a visiting team or by our own men.
>
> As far as their being shabbily treated I wish to call their attention to the fact that our boys took them to the restaurant and bought them their suppers, or they would have gone home on empty stomachs.
>
> They say it will be a long time before they play here again. Well, that suits us exactly, as we don't want to play with a lot of little boys that will get mad and **take their ball and go home** if we don't give them the game.
>
> They don't even know the first principals of "our National game" as they call it. The officials rules do not permit the pitcher to jump a foot of the box while in the act of delivering the ball, which their pitcher did, and then would not stop when his attention was called to it.

And from "[Tuttle Nine Is Victor with Aid of Two Umpires](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85042243/1919-08-04/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22ball%2Band%2Bgo%2Bhome%22)," in the *Bismarck [North Dakota] Tribune* (August 4, 1919):

> The ninth inning was the finest de­bating exhibition ever seen on the lo­cal ball field. Somebody threatened to **take h[i]s bat and ball and go home**, thus breaking up the game, but he was prevailed to stick around.

The earliest instances I could find where non-sporting behavior is compared to a child "taking his ball and going home" are from 1942. From "[International Officers' and Organizers' Reports: Report of Assistant International President J. N. Davis](https://books.google.com/books?id=ikpZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22ball+and+go+home%22&dq=%22ball+and+go+home%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSho2u46f5AhUEOH0KHcEECBQQ6AF6BAgCEAI)," in the *The Boilermaker Journal*, volume 54 (April 1942) [combined snippets]:

> ... yes, their are those who are virtually sitting in the midst of their particular group, conducting themselves in such a manner as to not only demoralize their own employes, but who threaten to demoralize the entire industry by involving other employers and by carrying on their continual line of propaganda to satisfy their hatred for all Labor that is free. It is high time that those who conduct themselves in such a manner be classified with the Fifth Columnist, for the Fifth Columnist could not do a better job and hide behind the Stars and Stripes. They remind me of certain boys when we played ball on the lots,  they either had to dictate the play and have all the breaks, or they would **take their ball and go home**.

And from an [unidentified document](https://books.google.com/books?id=wJZQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ball+and+go+home%22&dq=%22ball+and+go+home%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSho2u46f5AhUEOH0KHcEECBQQ6AF6BAgFEAI) in *Statement of the Allis-Chalmers Manufacturing Company in Negotiations with Local 248, U.A.W.A.-CIO: Before a Panel of the National War Labor Board*, volume 2 (1942) [snippet view]:

> Here at Allis-Chalmers, as long as the Union agrees with the company, it is considered "cooperative." When it independently expresses its opinion and speaks out for the interests of the workers whom it represents, the company always gets short-tempered like a child who wants **to take its ball and go home** because it can't pitch.

The earliest purely metaphorical use of the term that an Elephind newspaper database search turns up later still. From "[James Offers Four Indiana Sites to UNO for Wold Peace Capital](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=IPT19451208.1.1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22ball+and+go+home%22------)," in the *Indianapolis [Indiana] Times* (December 8, 1945):

> The lieutenant governor stressed that the U.S. would not "**take its ball and go home**" if the preparatory commission "does not play ball their way." He regretted that any impression might have been given that the U.S. would maintain interest in UNO only if the headquarters were in the United States.