# A proverb about a "sore loser"

Tags: proverbs, proverb-requests

Is there a proverb in the english language that describes a person with a "sore loser" type of attitude?

For example to convey a context, say there are two children (let's refer to them as Alice and Bob). Alice receives a doll for Christmas and Bob gets nothing. Feeling left out and angry, Bob breaks her doll.

Another maybe more realistic example, say there are a group of hackers/spies trying to intercept a particular communication. The encryption proves to be too much for their technology to handle so instead they do a DoS attack to take down the communication entirely.

In my language, we have a saying perfectly suited for this which loosely translates to "Either I join the game, or no games will be played". It seems like a common scenario to encounter in everyday life under many situations so I am hopeful that there could be one but proverbs are a tricky thing to look for because they are usually quite metaphorical in nature.

I am new to ESE so if the post can be improved let me know so I can edit it.

Comment: Hi Jepsilon.   Welcome to EL&U.  A "sore loser" is the best phrase to describe a sore loser.  Are you really looking for a proverb to describe it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [***take (one's) ball and go home***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+(one%27s)+ball+and+go+home) is almost an exact match
for your translated saying. 
It would typically be used in a context like

> It's my ball, so you must play the game the way I want
>   (e.g., make me the captain or the quarterback, etc.)
>   or I'll take my ball and go home
>   (and thereby prevent you from playing at all).

From [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+(one%27s)+ball+and+go+home):

> To be so petulant in dealing with adversity, loss, or rejection
>   that one quits or leaves abruptly,
>   often disrupting other participants in the process. 
>   The image is of a child who leaves with the ball,
>   thus preventing others from continuing to play the game.
>
> - *I didn't lose, you guys are playing wrong! 
>     That's it, I'm taking my ball and going home!*
> - *I've heard that this new artist is a little temperamental,
>     so, everyone, please be on your best behavior
>     so he doesn't take his ball and go home.*

Related: [“Take your ball and go home” - meaning of this odd phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11025/26083)

Answer (score 2):

[Taking my marbles and going home](https://unbridledacts.org/taking-my-marbles-going-home/) is another alternative

Comment: Hello @Niraj Agarwal. Welcome to the English S.E. If possible please elaborate more on your answer, as one line answers could be deleted.

Comment: Hi Niraj, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. Can I suggest you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., quote from the linked source to explain what the expression means? For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)